# Bottle.py application times out on mod_wsgi and uwsgi but works in dev mode

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, uwsgi

I have a bottle.py application that performs well in dev mode.  However, a function that has  a larger database query is causing the app to time out when run in either uwsgi or the browser to time out when run on mod_wsgi on apache.  How should I go about trying to achieve reasonable performance in a production environment?

Comment: So, does this larger database query "perform well" when it's run in the production environment in some way other than `uwsgi` or `mod_wsgi` (eg from the db commandline)?

Comment: There are no timeouts in mod_wsgi. Do you mean the browser times out?

Comment: Yes the query does perform well. DerfK  It usually returns in under .5 sec.  Graham, I mis typed, the browser is the timeout in mod_wsgi.  Uwsgi the time out appears server side.

Comment: To add some clarity to the test configuration.  I'm running all three servers simultaneously on the same box. The bottle.py server returns in <.5 sec